# creating an .so file with an so file and some other .o files

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a dynamic library(.so) from some .so files and some .o files.
The final so file is getting generated, but when I am using that .so file some of the libraries are not getting linked.

The thing is some .so files are getting linked, but some are not getting linked.  The one which is not linking is boost (.so) files.

`libboost_chrono.so.1.50.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just unpack [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hz6cgb6h40wfe7/chrono.tgz) into the same directory as the other libraries exists.

Comment: I am giving the path for the whole list of libraries. In that path the whole list of libraries are there. But, still its not getting linked.